# touchpad and keyboard don't work after upgrading to windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

touchpad and keyboard don't work after upgrading to windows 10, now I am unable to log into my laptop. I connected an external mouse which works but, the keyboard is still a problem as I am unable to punch in my password.

Comment: Have you tried connecting a USB keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try external keyboard to log in and then **re install** all drivers like touchpad driver and LAN drivers.